# Unproductive in my new job, and feeling inadequate

Tags: work-environment, new-job, resignation, work-experience

There has been no progress in my professional growth since I started my current job.  After begging and struggling, I finally got a project into the mainframes healthcare domain.

I find this project not only complicated, but there's nothing new or current to learn in that.  In spite of that, I started to learn it, but I didn't find my team very supportive. Below are the highlights:

1. My lead never assigns any tasks for me.
2. I make effort, but there has been no progress in the way people opine about me.  They think I am a failure capable of doing nothing.
3. It so happened that I was reviewing the requirements documents for the application enhancement, and I forwarded them to my office e-mail address from the client's machine, since my machine usually gets stuck or doesn't work.  My colleague literally shouted at me about this, and went desk-to-desk to humiliate me.  My manager and my leads scolded me, saying that I have come from a small company where they may not be following any ethics, but ours is a big company.  I was warned that one more mistake would cause them to get rid of me.

Thereafter, my lead hasn't assigned me much work.  But when she does, I try to complete it but somehow with the application I am usually stuck, and I need help.

My peers straight away refuse to help (but this happens occasionally not every-time.  I do get help, but not for everything.)

My manager now has told me to keep him posted about my task status every two hours. I have told him several times I don't get tasks that frequently.  What should I do then?

I have lost my confidence, efficiency, and my biggest hope which used to be my performance at my job.  Is there a way I can salvage this career choice?

Comment: Welcome to "The Workplace", please cut down your text a bit, the last part is a big wall-of-text. Furthermore please specify what your actual question is!

Comment: So wait... you think it's complicated but there is nothing to learn? That looks like a little bit of a contradiction. Also, you do have a project, but you do not have any tasks? I would suggest that you take all your courage and request a meeting with your lead to clarify your tasks in that project. You have to build your confidence by finishing some tasks, because if you go into interviews for a new job in the state of mind you currently seem to be in I see you struggling with doing well at interviews. First, recover. Then, re-decide if that's the job for you,

Comment: "[I find it] not only complicated but also there's nothing new to learn in that" - If it is complicated doesn't that mean there's something to learn? You may not enjoy it, however.

Comment: How long have you been at this current job?

Comment: i have been in this job for 10months, got allocated in the project in the month of Nov 2016.....

Answer (score 8):

This environment does not seem to be a good fit for you at all.  You should not have to beg, as you put it, for work to do.  (  The other key to what you should is that your job has *already been threatened*. )

I would suggest you do the best you can on your current job, and begin a new job search as soon as possible.  Remember its always easier to find a new job **when you have one currently,** so do not do anything rash to get yourself fired before you can move on by your own hand.

As mentioned in the comments, once you find a new job, work out your notice period and move on to what will hopefully be a better place for you.

Comment: + 1 for "does not seem to be a good fit for you". The company has expectations and an atmosphere that you are not seeming to fit into, regardless of the task assignments, etc. I wouldn't work there, not my bag to get yelled at or shouted down, but it's a personal choice for each of us as to what constitutes "motivation" and what is "abuse" (with some extreme exceptions...). you're obviously in the camp of "This is abusive to me" and it'd be best to find a new job, give notice and bolt.

Comment: thanks for your reply.... i am working towards your suggestion. I am a practical person, but still getting exhausted to inadvertant circumstances. I am happy you can up with this solution, and kind of spoke my mind.

Answer (score 1):

No one sidelines a productive developer who's new to a team without cause.  From my gut feeling, there's some critical piece missing here in this story.  I can't tell from the text if the OP was employed and put into a project right away, or if the OP was employed and then put on the bench for a while.

I've been in situations where a person's actual skill level was discovered -- after hiring -- to be *severely* less than was actually needed for the position.  The OP's comments seem to allude that this is the situation.  Qualified people don't need to check in with the manager every two hours to report status, but highly underqualified people (i.e. trainees) do.  The co-workers might be refusing to help the OP because of either:

- a perceived, or actual, lack of initiative on the OP's part.
- a perception that the OP feels entitled to interrupt others for help all day long.
- both of the above.

So **if** this is the case, then apparently no one is interested in "saving" an underperforming team member, and the OP is going to have to either dig herself out, find a new job, or wait around to get fired.

Comment: thanks but no tanks for the criticizing and sarcastic comments.. here the question was about the solution and not to express the personal point of view, if you can come out with something productive, postiive well and good, otherwise its not always important to speak, silence usually is the best answer.

Comment: There's apparently a pattern where you seem to believe others' criticism of you needs to be sugar-coated.  I don't agree with the yelling, but you can't make everyone else the bad guy forever, and make what happens to you everybody else's fault.  Just because you don't like my response doesn't make it untrue, and it's far easier to be dismissive than to consider the possibilities and correct yourself.

Comment: I've seen others fitting the same profile as you over 20+ years in the IT field.

Answer (score 0):

The most probable cause of this situation that you were employed for a task, for which meanwhile became clear that it is not needed (customer has step back, some yet bigger boss regrouped some human resources, anything). They won't admit it to you, instead they are trying now to utilize you for some another task.

If they are unsatisfied with you, it should have also other symptoms such as negative feedback, not nice talks with coworkers/leaders, etc. If there aren't, they aren't unsatisfied.

Another possible way is that somebody (typically, some lower level leader who decided your employment) doesn't like you, you were employed without his acknowledgement, and now he is working on your firing behind the walls. In this case, the company is badly organized, which is a red flag. If you get some negative feedbacks, and you know that they aren't true, but you can't prove it, probably this is the case.

It doesn't really matter, what is in the background. And don't worry, probably you won't ever know it. But it is not even important from the viewpoint, that in any case you should do the same:

- still try to do some useful
- look for your next job in the background.

Don't do anything which would make the forces behind your firing easier. Be nice, polite, positive, try to do what seems the best. Don't think that it is the apocalypse if you would be fired, instead make it so hard as you can. The company tries to defend his face for your false employment, if you show cooperativity now, it can be only useful in the future (and it makes a black point on the reputation of the .... who is firing you).

Comment: @JoeStrazzere If they are unsatisified, it doesn't only result that he doesn't get a real task, but also some other consquences should follow (negative feedbacks, not nice talks with coworkers/leaders, any similar). I don't know how could I formulate better, is it understable now?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of @codenoir answer not to personally criticize you. He was just trying to tell you to look down to yourself.  by your story, i think there are only 2 possibilities.  either your team has already more than enough member, or you are useless for the team (your presence has no effect on team).

You can't always hope for others to treat you with kindness in this cruelty world. there are sayings "If you're easy to yourself, then the world's gonna hard to you.  If you're hard to yourself, then the world's gonna easy to you"

if you really want to survive in your job, you need to quickly learn how to use the application you usually stucked on. search for it on internet, you can learn from there.

other way i can think of is by asking for private mentoring from one of your colleague, for it to work, you need to build friendship, sometimes money can 'buy' friendship. go treat them for lunch, karaoke, anything. if they like you, you will get more chance to success.

Comment: thanks....... but no thanks as well...... i could buy friendship for sure, but the person should be in  the mood to sell as well. World is a cruel place, but not all things are practical...and yes, i never hope for Kindness from anyone, if i did, i would have been sitting here complaining about them....

Comment: i don't really need your thanks. from your answer to others i can tell that you are a really pessimistic person. the best thing you can do is quit your job and just do something you really good at. the one you can't get stuck on. you just come here to complain that people were being rude and cruel to you. you were protecting yourself from any critics. everyone here wants to help you, but seems that you would only accept answer that pleases you and perhaps the one which you already  know or have in your head.  if nothing important this would be my last respond,  good luck to you.